Syntax problems with EXTRACT and DATE
Bigquery suggest me 'EXTRACT' funtion syntax:
extract(datetime_part FROM timestamp_expr [AT TIME ZONE tz_spec])

However, Bigquery notice "Unexpected keyword AT". Moreover, it's syntax in official Bigquery document is totally different.
Similar case with 'Date' function. Can anyone explain this? What should i fill in syntax is suggested by BQ? Does have any similar cases? Thanks you!!
An clear explaination.

Maybe you have just misunderstood the syntax description. The brackets must not be typed. They just mean that the part AT TIME ZONE tz_spec is optional.

I changed the title to a more descriptive one. Imagine someone else having problems with the EXTRACT syntax... Would they look for a topic titled "weird syntax"? Probably not.

@ThorstenKettner thanks for your comment, It is usefull. I will mind for future title.

The allowed syntax depends on whether the operand is a DATE, a DATETIME or a TIMESTAMP.
EXTRACT function
For a TIMESTAMP:
EXTRACT(part FROM timestamp_expression [AT TIME ZONE time_zone])

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#extract
For a DATE or DATETIME:
EXTRACT(part FROM date_expression)

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract
DATE function
For a TIMESTAMP:
DATE(timestamp_expression [, time_zone_expression])

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date
(It's a bit confusing that they have this under "date functions" and not "timestamp functions", because while the result is a date, the function is applied on a timestamp and should hence be put in that chapter.)
For a DATETIME:
DATE(datetime_expression)

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date

Not being a BigQuery developer, I was a bit surprised at these syntaxes, too. I would have expected AT TIME ZONE to be a TIMESTAMP operator which you can apply to a timestamp in any situation (and hence thought I could look this up in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators). Obviously, this isn't the case. AT TIME ZONE is not an operator unfortunately, but part of the respective function syntax, and with EXTRACT you can use this syntax, while with DATE you must state the time zone as a parameter instead. A bit of a weakness in design.
